# Why are hex digits not passed correctly in python subprocess

Tags: python, hex, subprocess, parameter-passing

I cannot get ping to insert a pattern with python subprocess.Popen... Using 2.6.

Test: open python interpreter...

```
import subprocess
a = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-c 1', '-p ff', '172.16.1.1'],subprocess.PIPE)
```

Result ... ping: patterns must be specified as hex digits.

I have replaced the ff with: "f", "23", 23, 0x23 and a range of things. I just want to see what the shell thinks its getting. But shell=True did not do as I expect, a.communicate() gives (none,none)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you split all your "words" into their own list entry:

```
a = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-c', '1', '-p' 'ff', '172.16.1.1'],subprocess.PIPE)
# PING 172.16.1.1 (172.16.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

The way you had it, your command was executed as

```
ping -c\ 1 -p\ ff 172.16.1.1
```

(the spaces between the args and their value is escaped)

Comment: This works well  thank you. Can you give me a way to verify this? An easy way to validate what you say visually, it would be helpful.

Comment: When you're in the terminal, you can write `-p ff` or `-pff`. In the first case, the space is ignored. However, when you escape the space like `-p\ ff`, it's not ignored. It becomes part of the hex value. Ping will accept `ff` but not `_ff` (where `_` is a leading space).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to answer by Martin Konecny: import `shlex` and let it do the work for you.

```
subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('ping -c 1 -p ff 127.0.0.1'), subprocess.PIPE)
```